# Routing issue in MVC + WEB API + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

1. I got `BroserController`, which is ordinary MVC-controller. At the same time I have `BrowsingDataController` controller (api/controller/method) - web api service, returning Json.
2. At the load of my single-page app following angular code is executed: `...$http.get('api/browsingdata/CurrentLocation')...`. If current browser-URL is just 'localhost:' - everything works fine. But if I go 'localhost:/Browser/Index', then `$http.get` does stuipid thing: it creates `localhost:/BROWSER/api/browsingdata/CurrentLocation' string, which is obviously wrong.

How can I fix that?

Comment: 'localhost:/Browser/Index' has a colon in there which might be fouling things up

Comment: It you're hosting the app on port 80 just remove the colon otherwise put the actual port number after the colon. Please also paste your $http defaults settings and interceptors.

Comment: No, guys. The problem is URL that generated in `...$http.get('api/browsingdata/CurrentLocation')...`. If user runs localhost/Browser/Launch, generated request is WRONG.